# Unable to bypass cloudflare captcha on ahrefs.com using its free dr service (using "seleniumbase")

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, seleniumbase

Here's my code: (I'm using `seleniumbase` to access the website)

```py
from seleniumbase import SB, Driver
import time 

with SB(uc=True, test=True) as sb:
    url = "https://ahrefs.com/website-authority-checker"
    sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 3)
    sb.type('/html/body/div/div[1]/section[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div/div[1]/div/input', 'https://www.peopleperhour.com')
    time.sleep(2)
    sb.click('/html/body/div/div[1]/section[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/button')
    time.sleep(10)
    sb.post_message("SeleniumBase wasn't detected", duration=4)
```

[image: captcha asking me to verify but keeps on going]

I'm trying to get some stats related to website strength (dr, backlink, linking_websites) but a cloudflare captcha is in the way, even though I'm using seleniumbase. Here's the video link where I learned about seleniumbase:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dMFI3e85ig

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) script that works for that page:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB


with SB(uc=True, test=True, locale_code="en") as sb:
    url = "https://ahrefs.com/website-authority-checker"
    sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 4)
    sb.type('input[placeholder="Enter domain"]', "https://www.peopleperhour.com")
    sb.driver.uc_click('span:contains("Check Authority")', reconnect_time=4)

    breakpoint()
```

Type `c` and press `Enter` to continue from the `breakpoint()`.

[image]

Comment: It Worked thnks a lot.